# Does the Flight hex grant a bonus to the Fly skill, like the spell does?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, skills, witch

Does a character still get the bonus to the fly skill as per the spell Fly when using the witch's hex Flight?

The Flight hex reads: "she can fly, as per the spell"

The Fly spell reads: "The subject gains a bonus on Fly skill checks equal to 1/2 your caster level."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Yes, sort of.

The [Flight hex](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes---3rd-party-publishers/hexes/common-hexes/hex-flight-su) allows you to fly as if using the spell [Fly](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fly). Thus because Fly grants a bonus to Fly checks equal to half the spells caster level, this also applies to the Flight Hex.

Note however that the [Hex](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch) Witch class feature nor the Flight hex itself specify what the caster level is for Fly component of the Flight hex (opposed by the [Healing hex](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/hexes---3rd-party-publishers/hexes/common-hexes/hex-healing-su), which does specify a caster lv). This is important because the Fly spell's bonus is dependent on caster lv.

Though quite frankly, it's probably safe to assume the caster level is supposed to be equal to the Witch's class lv.